# Inheriting struct which is forward declared?

Tags: c++, inheritance, forward-declaration

Can't I inherit from a structure that was only forward-declared?

Example:

```
struct A;
class B : public A {};
```

I am getting the error "base class is undefined".

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can't do so. First of all, when you inherit from a structure or class, its size must be known. But the compiler can't determine the size if the struct was just forward declared. And the compiler also needs to know what kind of members the super-class has, e.g. if there are any `virtual` functions, etc.

Comment: In fact the type has to be complete. More than just the size needs to be known in order to determine effective class layout, member initialization, virtuality of constructors, virtuality of repeated bases, name hiding/ambiguities etc. The whole class declaration is required

Comment: @sehe agreed, size is just one thing that needs to be known. How would you know if a method overrides a virtual base class method for example?

Answer (score 3):

You must actually include the base class header when you derive from a class. Forward declaration is not enough